# Não consigo remover o novo item criado em minha Todo List - Usando Vanilla

Tags: javascript

Os itens que já estão na lista eu consigo deletar, mas depois que eu adiciono um novo item na lista, o remove não funciona mais. Tomei o cuidado de criar a mesma classe para o meu SPAN antes de adicioná-lo em minha li, mas ainda não funcionou.

```js
//Seleciona Span 
var itens = document.getElementsByClassName("item")

//Deleta Li
for(var i = 0; i < itens.length; i++){
    itens[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
       var li = this.closest("li");
       li.classList.add("deletar");
      
       setTimeout(() => li.parentElement.removeChild(li), 500);
    });
};


//Seleciona Input
var input = document.querySelector("input");

//Adiciona novo item na lista
input.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
      if(event.which === 13){
        var minhaLi = document.createElement("li");
        var meuSpan = document.createElement("span");
        var meuIcone = document.createElement("i");
        
        var minhaUl = document.querySelector("ul");

        var novoTexto = input.value;
        //this.value = " ";

        meuIcone.classList.add('fa','fa-trash');
        meuSpan.classList.add("item");
        meuSpan.append(meuIcone);

        minhaUl.appendChild(minhaLi).append(meuSpan, novoTexto);
         
      };
});
```

```css
body{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background: #50C9C3;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #96DEDA, #50C9C3);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #96DEDA, #50C9C3); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

h1{
    background: #2980b9;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li{
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #666;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .8s;
}

li.deletar {
    opacity: 0;
  }


li:nth-child(2n+1){
    background: #fff;
}

input{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #2980b9;
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    padding: 13px 13px 13px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input:focus{
    background: white;
    border: 3px solid #2980b9;
    outline:none;
}

span{
    background-color: #e74c3c;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    width: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: 0.2s linear;
    opacity: 0;
}

li:hover span{
    width: 40px;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

.container{
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 360px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rbga(0,0,0,0.1);
    background: #f7f7f7;
}

.selecao{
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

.fa-plus{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Todo List</title>
        
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>To-do List <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></h1>
            <input id="adicionaItem" type="text" placeholder="Add New Todo">
            <ul>  
                <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Estudar programação part I</li>
                <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Cuidar do Artur</li>
                <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Preparar almoço</li>
                <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Fazer exercícios de Sérvio</li>
                <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Estudar programação part II</li>
                <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Comer um chocolate</li>
                <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Lavar a louça</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/Todo2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Apesar de ter conseguido fazer a minha Todo List com Jquery, não consigo repetir a lógica com Vanilla. Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque os elementos criados de forma dinâmica não foram adicionados no seu `for` quando a página foi carregada.

Para que o click seja reconhecido para elementos quando a página foi carregada e para elementos adicionados após, substitua o trecho do código abaixo:

```
//Deleta Li
for(var i = 0; i < itens.length; i++){
    itens[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
       var li = this.closest("li");
       li.classList.add("deletar");

       setTimeout(() => li.parentElement.removeChild(li), 500);
    });
};
```

por:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (e){
   if(~e.target.className.indexOf("item") || ~e.target.className.indexOf("trash")){

      var li = ~e.target.className.indexOf("item") ?
      e.target.parentNode :
      e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
      li.classList.add("deletar");
      setTimeout(() => li.parentElement.removeChild(li), 500);
   }

});
```

E delete a linha abaixo que não é mais necessária:

```
//Seleciona Span 
var itens = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
```

O código vai identificar se o que foi clicado foi a classe `.item` ou `.trash` e remover a linha correspondente.

**Veja:**

```js
//Deleta Li
document.addEventListener("click", function (e){
   if(~e.target.className.indexOf("item") || ~e.target.className.indexOf("trash")){
      
      var li = ~e.target.className.indexOf("item") ?
      e.target.parentNode :
      e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
      li.classList.add("deletar");
      setTimeout(() => li.parentElement.removeChild(li), 500);
   }
   
});

//Seleciona Input
var input = document.querySelector("input");

//Adiciona novo item na lista
input.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
      if(event.which === 13){
        var minhaLi = document.createElement("li");
        var meuSpan = document.createElement("span");
        var meuIcone = document.createElement("i");
        
        var minhaUl = document.querySelector("ul");

        var novoTexto = input.value;
        //this.value = " ";

        meuIcone.classList.add('fa','fa-trash');
        meuSpan.classList.add("item");
        meuSpan.append(meuIcone);

        minhaUl.appendChild(minhaLi).append(meuSpan, novoTexto);
         
      };
});
```

```css
body{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background: #50C9C3;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #96DEDA, #50C9C3);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #96DEDA, #50C9C3); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

h1{
    background: #2980b9;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li{
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #666;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .8s;
}

li.deletar {
    opacity: 0;
  }


li:nth-child(2n+1){
    background: #fff;
}

input{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #2980b9;
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    padding: 13px 13px 13px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input:focus{
    background: white;
    border: 3px solid #2980b9;
    outline:none;
}

span{
    background-color: #e74c3c;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    width: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: 0.2s linear;
    opacity: 0;
}

li:hover span{
    width: 40px;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

.container{
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 360px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rbga(0,0,0,0.1);
    background: #f7f7f7;
}

.selecao{
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

.fa-plus{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
   <h1>To-do List <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></h1>
   <input id="adicionaItem" type="text" placeholder="Add New Todo">
   <ul>  
       <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Estudar programação part I</li>
       <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Cuidar do Artur</li>
       <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Preparar almoço</li>
       <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Fazer exercícios de Sérvio</li>
       <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Estudar programação part II</li>
       <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Comer um chocolate</li>
       <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Lavar a louça</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```